# Azure Service Fabric deployment fails from VS 2015 RC

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm getting the following error when deploying an Actor service from Visual Studio 2015, either via right clicking the Application project and selecting 'Deploy' or hitting F5:

*Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage : The term 'Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage' is not recognized as the name 
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.*

I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2.

I've tried running Import-Module "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ServiceFabric\ServiceFabric.psd1", but always get the same error.

If I use PS to run the same script VS runs, the deployment works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rudy

Comment: My workaround for now has been to modify the PS scripts in the solution to import the Service Fabric module. That works, but it's still a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1) Go to c:\SFDevCluster\Log\Traces. you will see one or more TRACE Files

2) Open the one that starts with FabricSetup-* using a text editor.it should tell you want is going wrong.

3) If the setup step was successful, then open the file that starts with fabricdeployer-*. If you find multiple files, then start by opening the latest and work your way down.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

1. Go to powershell and execute DevCluster.ps1 directly
2. If you still see the issue, close the powershell command and reopen.
3. Again execute the same script (Sometimes the variables are not properly set, that's why we need to reopen powershell)
4. If the cluster is up then continue with deployment using F5, now instead of creating the cluster , it will start with deployment of application